# Binding event to dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm creating  elements dynamically but I'm having problems to attache events to this elements.

Here's the code:

```
$selectUnitedStates = '<option value="americanEnglish" id="americanEnglish">English</option>';

$selectUnitedKingdom = '<option value="englishEnglish" id="englishEnglish">English</option>';

$selectGermany = '<option value="german" id="german">German</option>';

$selectFrance = '<option value="frenchFrench" id="frenchFrench">French</option>';

$selectItaly = '<option value="italian" id="italian">Italian</option>';

$selectCanada = '<option value="canadianEnglish" id="canadianEnglish">English</option>' +
        '<option value="canadianFrench" id="canadianFrench">French</option>';

$selectDenmark = '<option value="danish" id="danish">Danish</option>';

$selectFinland = '<option value="finnish" id="finnish">Finnish</option>';

$selectSweden = '<option value="swedish" id="swedish">Swedish</option>';

$('#country').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            success: function () {
                if ($('#country').val() === 'UnitedStates') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectUnitedStates);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'UnitedKingdom') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectUnitedKingdom);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Germany') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectGermany);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'France') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectFrance);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Italy') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectItaly);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Canada') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectCanada);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Denmark') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectDenmark);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Finland') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectFinland);
                }
                if ($('#country').val() === 'Sweden') {
                    $('#language').html("");
                    $('#language').html($selectSweden);
                }
            }
        });
```

(I'm not sure if there's a better way to do populate the options)

and here's the function that I'm having problems with:

```
$('body').on('change', '#englishEnglish', function () {
        $desiredLanguageEmail = $labelEmailUK;
        $desiredLanguageFirstName = $labelFirstNameUK;
        $desiredLanguageLastName = $labelLastNameUK;
        $desiredLanguageCompany = $labelCompanyUK;
        $desiredLanguageIndustry = $labelIndustryUK;
        $desiredLanguagePhone = $labelPhoneUK;
        $desiredLanguageCountry = $labelCountryUK;
        console.log($desiredLanguageEmail);
    });
```

According to jquery documentation that the correct way to bind and event to a dynamic element, but it's not working

Any ideas?

Comment: `#englishEnglish` is an `option`, you need to bind the `change` event to the `select` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be binding the `change` event to the `<select>` element. Since the `<select>` is not created dynamically, only the `<option>`s, you don't need to use delegation. Then you need to test the value that the user selected. So it should be:

```
$("#language").change(function() {
    switch($(this).val()) {
    case "englishEnglish":
        $desiredLanguageEmail = $labelEmailUK;
        $desiredLanguageFirstName = $labelFirstNameUK;
        $desiredLanguageLastName = $labelLastNameUK;
        $desiredLanguageCompany = $labelCompanyUK;
        $desiredLanguageIndustry = $labelIndustryUK;
        $desiredLanguagePhone = $labelPhoneUK;
        $desiredLanguageCountry = $labelCountryUK;
        console.log($desiredLanguageEmail);
        break;
    case "americanEnglish":
        $desiredLanguageEmail = $labelEmailUS;
        $desiredLanguageFirstName = $labelFirstNameUS;
        $desiredLanguageLastName = $labelLastNameUS;
        $desiredLanguageCompany = $labelCompanyUS;
        $desiredLanguageIndustry = $labelIndustryUS;
        $desiredLanguagePhone = $labelPhoneUS;
        $desiredLanguageCountry = $labelCountryUS;
        console.log($desiredLanguageEmail);
        break;
    ...
}
```

FYI, there's no need to use `$("#language").html("")` before `$("#language").html(somethingElse)`, since the second statement replaces whatever was there before.

Also, instead of having 7 different variables, and an enormous `switch` statement to set them all differently for each language, it would probably be better to create an object that collected them, keyed off the language:

```
var langLabels = {
    "englishEnglish": {
        email: "Email",
        firstName: "First Name",
        lastName: "Surname",
        company: "Company",
        industry: "Industry",
        phone: "Phone #",
        country: "Country"
    },
    "frenchfrench": {
        email: "Email",
        firstName: "Prénom",
        lastName: "Nom de Famille",
        company: "Compagnie",
        industry: "Industrie",
        phone: "Téléphone",
        country: "Pays"
    },
    ...
}
```

Then your `.change` handler can just do:

```
var $desiredLanguage = $langLabels[$(this).val()];
$desiredLanguageEmail = $desiredLanguage.email;
$desiredLanguageFirstName = $desiredLanguage.firstName;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the change event to the select instead of one of the options:

```
$('body').on('change', '#yourLanguageSelectId', function () {
    $desiredLanguageEmail = $labelEmailUK;
    $desiredLanguageFirstName = $labelFirstNameUK;
    $desiredLanguageLastName = $labelLastNameUK;
    $desiredLanguageCompany = $labelCompanyUK;
    $desiredLanguageIndustry = $labelIndustryUK;
    $desiredLanguagePhone = $labelPhoneUK;
    $desiredLanguageCountry = $labelCountryUK;
    console.log($desiredLanguageEmail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (assuming `#country` is the id of your select element):

```
$(document).on('change', '#country', function() {
    // do whatever you wanted to do here
});
```